# Expanding or collapsing layer groups with PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, layers, pyqgis-3

PyQGIS 2 has a function to expand/collapse a layers with a subset of styles in the Layers panel as follows:

```
self.iface.legendInterface().setLayerExpanded(self.segments_layer, False)
```

I know that in PyQGIS 3 `self.iface.legendInterface()` has been replaced by `gsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()` but making that switch in this case produces an error:

> AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTree' object has no attribute 'setLayerExpanded'

What is the appropriate replacement for `setLayerExpanded` in PyQGIS 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it from the [QgsLayerTreeNode::setExpanded()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html#a86b03df69ebcce2733f9cc3f191caa40) function:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_Name')[0]
myLayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
myLayerNode.setExpanded(True)
```

Comment: @CNIDog - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean up a giant list of expanded group layers in the table of contents, here's a few lines of PyQGIS that'll do the trick (i.e. collapse all group layers):

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
nodes = root.children()

for n in nodes:
    if isinstance(n, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        if n.isExpanded() == True:
            n.setExpanded(False)
            print(f"Layer group '{n.name()}' now collapsed.")
```